# Android capture and use image not working

Tags: android

I've written code in Android to capture an image and then use that image as follows:

```
private static Intent i;
final static int cons = 0;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public void takePicture()
{
    i= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); //Open camera
    startActivityForResult(i, cons);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("Testing if condition", "Test"); //This code does not execute
            Bundle ext = data.getExtras();
            Log.d("Upload image", ext.toString());
            sendForUpload(data); // function to upload file to server
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

This code lets me take a photo and it saves to the SD card. However, I'm not sure if the file is sent to the `sendForUpload` function where I've handled getting the path and uploading the file. In fact nothing inside the  `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)` block works. How do I use the image captured from this activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a few problems.

First, you are calling `startActivityForResult(i, cons);`. `cons` is `0`. You are trying to compare `0` with `CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE`. Since `CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE` is `100`, that will not work.

Second, you are calling `data.getExtras().toString()` (split over two Java statements). I would expect this to return a value like `android.os.Bundle@34334143`. If that is what you want to upload, fine. I am guessing that you want to upload the image. Since you did not include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, you get a `Bitmap` of the thumbnail image taken by the camera via `data.getParcelableExtra("data")`.

Third, you are making inappropriate assumptions:

> This code lets me take a photo and it saves to the SD card.

There is no requirement for the camera app to save the image anywhere, let alone to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). In fact, I would argue that this is a bug in your camera app. That is not surprising, as [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations have bugs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html).

> where I've handled getting the path and uploading the file

There is no path. You did not include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, and so all you get back is the thumbnail `Bitmap`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this to put the image in a ImageView:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

You can use bitmap or uri objects for upload or show your picture..

Hope it helps you.

Comment: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`. A few camera app implementations do this, but not most of them, because that is not part of [the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

Comment: I'm just sharing  what i'm using and working for me ^^

Comment: Your code will fail on Nexus-series devices, as `getData()` will return `null`. It will fail for any other camera app, whether pre-installed or installed by the user, that follows the documentation.

Comment: Ohh, probably you are rigth.. I'm very new in Android.. Thank you, I will test and fix the problems ^^